# How to properly use integral identity for loop calculations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

#### Setup

For the following let us define
$$I_{\alpha}(\sigma) :=\mu^{2 \epsilon} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{D} k}{(2 \pi)^{D}} \left(\frac{1}{k^{2}-\sigma^{2}}\right)^\alpha 
$$
and assume that the following holds for $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$
$$I_{\alpha+1}(\sigma)=\frac{D-2 \alpha}{2 \alpha} \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} I_{\alpha}(\sigma).$$

#### Problem

To calculate $I_1(\sigma)$ one uses dimensional regularization with the result
$$I_1(\sigma) =\frac{i \sigma^{2}}{16 \pi^{2}}\left[\frac{1}{\bar{\epsilon}}+\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\right)+1\right]+\mathcal{O}(\bar{\epsilon}),
$$
where $1/\bar\epsilon := 1/\epsilon -\gamma_E +\ln(4\pi)$. But what happens then to for example $I_3$, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}I_3(\sigma) &= \frac{D-4}{4} \frac{1}{\sigma^2} I_{2}(\sigma) = \frac{D-4}{4}\frac{D-2}{2} \frac{1}{\sigma^4} I_1(\sigma) \\
&= \frac{D-4}{4}\frac{D-2}{2} \frac{1}{\sigma^4} \frac{i \sigma^{2}}{16 \pi^{2}}\left[\frac{1}{\bar{\epsilon}}+\log \left(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\right)+1\right]+\mathcal{O}(\bar{\epsilon}). \end{align*}$$
We cannot set $D=4$, b.c. then the term $D-4$ would imply $I_3=0$. If we on the other hand set $D=4-2\epsilon$ as we did for the dimensional regularization, then $I_3\propto \epsilon$, which is also useless since in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ we again get $I_3=0$. This implies $I_n=0$ for $n\ge 3$, which would make me question why even bother with these integrals...

Down below is a more involved example to show how this can arise in an actual calculation.

---

#### Example

Consider a QFT with one heavy scalar field of mass $M$ and one light scalar of mass $m$. The one loop correction to the two-point function of the light scalar, that involves the heavy scalar, will be proportional to
$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{D} k}{(2 \pi)^{D}} \frac{1}{k^{2}-m^{2}} \frac{1}{(k+p)^{2}-M^{2}} &\approx \int \frac{d^{D} k}{(2 \pi)^{D}} \frac{1}{k^{2}-m^{2}} 
  \left( \frac{1}{k^2-M^2}- \frac{p^2 + 2k\cdot p}{(k^2-M^2)^2}+\frac{4(k\cdot p)^2}{(k^2-M^2)^3}\right)
\\ &=:A_1 + A_2+A_3,
\end{align*}$$
where we used the approximation
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(k+p)^{2}-\sigma^{2}}&=\frac{1}{k^{2}-\sigma^{2}}-\frac{p^{2}+2 k \cdot p}{\left(k^{2}-\sigma^{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{4(k \cdot p)^{2}}{\left(k^{2}-\sigma^{2}\right)^{3}}+\mathcal{O}\left(p^{3}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Let's now take $A_2$ as an example and continue
$$\begin{align*}
A_2 &:= -\int \frac{d^{D} k}{(2 \pi)^{D}} \frac{1}{k^{2}-m^{2}} 
   \frac{p^2 + 2k\cdot p}{(k^2-M^2)^2}= -2p^2 \int_0^1 dx\, x\, I_3(\sqrt{\Delta}),
\end{align*}$$
where $\Delta := m^2+(M^2-m^2)x$ and the result was obtained by introducing Feynman parameters and noticing that the terms proportional to $k^\mu$ in the momentum integral give zero. We then have
$$I_3(\sqrt{\Delta}) = \frac{D-4}{4} \frac{1}{\Delta} I_{2}(\sqrt{\Delta}) = \frac{D-4}{4}\frac{D-2}{2} \frac{1}{\Delta^2} I_1(\sqrt{\Delta}). $$
For $D=4$ we therefore get $I_3=0$ and therefore $A_2=0$. I know that this is wrong...

Comment: I haven't gone through your calculation, but are you not just considering the divergent part and what does that mean for $\int d^Dk /k^{2\alpha}$ for $D=4$ and $\alpha>2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter is simply due to the fact that you used an approximation of the integral and not the integral itself. It is easy to show that integrating in $1+(D-1)$ dimensions yield:
\begin{equation*}
I_\alpha (\sigma)=\frac{i}{(4\pi)^{D/2}}(-1)^{-\alpha}\sigma^{D-2\alpha} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-D/2)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}.
\end{equation*}
Then, when you use your formula for iteration in $\alpha$ you have :
\begin{equation*}
I_{\alpha+1}\propto \left(1-\frac{D}{2\alpha}\right)\Gamma\left( \alpha-\frac{D}{2} \right) \neq 0,
\end{equation*}
as $\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+\mathcal{O}(z)$ with $\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant.